# Other way to "wait" during javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, settimeout

i'm looking for another way to execute this code :

```
$.each($("#gallery > img"), function(index,curImg) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            clearCanvas();
            cvsCtx.drawImage(curImg,0,0);
        } , index*animationMs);

    });
```

This code draw an image from my gallery to my canvas every  *animationMs* . 
But i would like to make it possible to stop the animation, with a "Play/stop" button, I can't do it this way...
Any idea or workaround ?? thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that creating timeouts in a loop is usually too hard to manage - you don't want to have to cancel multiple timeouts. Better to have the function doing the work call itself (indirectly) by setting a timeout just before it completes, because then you can put in a simple if test to decide whether to set the next timeout and continue your animation.

Perhaps a little something like this:

```
<input id="playPause" type="button" value="Play">

<script>    
function initAnimation(animationMs, autoRepeat, waitForPlayButton) {
    var currentFrame = 0,
        $imgList = $("#gallery > img"),
        paused = waitForPlayButton;

    function drawNext() {
       clearCanvas();
       cvsCtx.drawImage($imgList[currentFrame++],0,0);

       if (currentFrame >= $imgList.length) {
           currentFrame = 0;
           if (!autoRepeat) {
              paused = true;
              $("playPause").prop("value", "Play");
           }
       }
       if (!paused)
           setTimeout(drawNext, animationMs);
    }

    $("playPause").prop("value", waitForPlayButton ? "Play" : "Pause")
                  .click(function() {
                      this.value = (paused = !paused) ? "Play" : "Pause";
                      if (!paused)
                         drawNext();
                  });
    if (!waitForPlayButton)
       drawNext();
}

initAnimation(100, true, false);
</script>
```

If `autoRepeat` param is false the animation will run once and stop, but can be restarted via the button, otherwise (obviously) it just keeps repeating.

If `waitForPlayButton` is false the animation will start immediately, otherwise (obviously) it will start when the button is pressed.

Pressing the button will pause at the current frame.

(Not tested since I don't have a bunch of images handy, but I'm sure you get the idea and can fix any problems yourself. Or let me know if you get errors...)

Comment: i have to test this when i come back home but I think this could be a solution to my problem...

Comment: This is great, your code works "out of the box" !! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it. But you can stop animation by using a variable to hold the setTimeout function as following:

```
var x; // public var
....
x = setTimeout(......);
// To stop it use:
clearTimeout(x);
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: True, but there are N such `x`s (for N images), so you'd need to track all of them.

Comment: Yep I need to track all images so it doesn't work, but thank you anyway. I have to try others

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = $("#gallery > img").clone(), interval;

function startLoop() {
  interval = setInterval(function(){
      var image = images[0];
      clearCanvas();
      cvsCtx.drawImage(image,0,0);
      images.append(image);
  }, animationMs);
}

$(".stop").click(function() {clearInterval(interval);});
$(".start").click(startLoop);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout return a timeoutID which can be given to clearTimeout as a parameter to stop the timeout from happening.

You can read more about this at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an animation... but still:

```
$("#gallery > img").each(function(index,curImg) {
    $(this).delay(index*animationMs).queue(function(next) {    
       clearCanvas();
       cvsCtx.drawImage(curImg,0,0);
       if (next) next();
    });
});
```

Using jQuery queues like I did allows you to do `.stop(true)`, on `$("#gallery > img")` or a single image and stop their "animation".

Answer (score 0):

First you could add images to a javascript array variable (eventually global) and then call a function `cycle()` on that array for all its length. 
You should put your `setTimeout()` call inside that function, assigning it to a variable: `var t=setTimeout("cycle()",animationMs);` and execute `clearTimeout(t);` when you want to stop the animation.

Of course you could also save in a variable the frame where you were when stopping the animation and restart exactly from that frame when pressing "play" button.